# Написание телеграм бота на пайтон для удаления сообщений в тг чате

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

нужно написать телеграм бота на пайтон который будет удалять сообщение в телеграм чате которые содержат матерные слова, как сделать, понятия не имею, очень прошу помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы создать подобного бота, можете использовать библиотеку telebot. Примерный план разработки:

1)Инициализировать бота.

2)Повесить слушатель событий на сообщения

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
```

3. Искать во всех сообщения банворды и удалять те, в которых банворд присутствует

```py
ban_words=["кот", "собака", "змея"]
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def check_message(message):
    for word in ban_words:
        if word.lower() in message.text.lower():
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Прошу заметить, что мой ответ не является окончательным решением и работы вам предстоит ещё много:)

P.S.: список матов можно достать [тут](https://www.myadept.ru/index.php/page/spisok-necenzurnyh-slov-dlja-anti-spama-i-cenzury)

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за ответ, пишет ошибку при объявлении листа

Comment: Добрый, я писал, что моё решение - это лишь кусок кода, который вам нужно доработать. Если у вас возникают какие-либо проблемы - вы можете создать об этом отдельную ветку.